# Como evitar SQL Injection em minha aplicação PHP?

Tags: php, sql, segurança, sql-injection

## Explicação:

A maioria das aplicações utilizando PHP, devem receber parâmetros, por `$_GET` ou `$_POST` e estes parâmetros muitas vezes se tornam um alvo fácil para os usuários com más intenções, e isso se chama SQL Injection.

## Pergunta:

Gostaria de saber como evitar que minha aplicação seja atacada via SQL Injection, como proceder?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-injecao-de-codigo-sql-no-meu-codigo-php

Comment: @Sergio vejo que a pergunta é sobre o mesmo conceito porém é limitado ao conteúdo preposto pelo OP da pergunta, não?

Comment: Essa afirmação não é verdadeira: "A maioria das aplicações utilizando PHP, devem receber parâmetros, por $_GET ou $_POST e estes parâmetros muitas vezes se tornam um alvo fácil para os usuários com más intenções, e isso se chama SQL Injection.". Get ou Post podem ser utilizados como porta de entrada para uma série de coisas com problema. A injeção de SQL por acaso pode acontecer por estes meios também, mas são conceitos sem nenhuma relação direta.

Answer (score 6):

Você deve codificar todos os parâmetros passados para a sua aplicação antes de concatenar ao seu SQL. Todos os bancos de dados suportam de alguma forma salvar dados no banco, mesmo que seja um SQL, e para isso o valor deve estar devidamente codificado.

**Métodos úteis para codificar as strings:**

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) -> depois de usar este método e escapar a string, você poderá concatenar no SQL a ser executado.

**Ou então use métodos que executam SQL, que levam parâmetros**

Existem bibliotecas que permitem indicar um único SQL, com marcadores de parâmetro no meio do SQL, sendo que esses marcadores são substituídos de forma a evitar injeção de SQL.

Exemplo:

```
$con  = new mysqli("localhost", "u", "p", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die(mysqli_connect_error());

$sql  = "INSERT INTO articles (title, body, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$ok   = $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST[title], $_POST[body]);

if ($ok && $stmt->execute())
  header('Location: index.php');
else
  die('Error: '.$con->error);
```

[Origem do exemplo no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2592297/195417)

Answer (score 3):

## Comentários pessoais

Vejo várias pessoas, inclusive aqui no SOPT, cometendo o erro de deixar sua aplicação vulnerável à SQL Injection, claro que por falta de informação, porém **é de suma importância dizer que é essencial hoje em dia prevenir este tipo de ataque**, pois é conhecido por um bocado de pessoas mal intencionadas.

## Explicações:

### "Como funciona o SQL Injection?"

O SQL Injection como diz no nome traduzido para "Injeção SQL", nada mais é do que um script SQL que é executado em seu banco por alguém que não tem acesso à ele, desta forma deixando seu banco totalmente vulnerável à qualquer coisa que o usuário mal intencionado queira fazer.

### "Como/Porque os usuários mal intencionados conseguem fazer isso?"

O problema está em algumas aplicações PHP que utilizam parâmetros que estão presentes na URL ou até mesmo os parâmetros escondidos que você passa no cabeçalho de sua URL, para preencher dados em um script SQL.

#### Exemplo:

Você tem uma aplicação que precisa de um `ID` para realizar um `SELECT`, até aí tudo bem, porém vamos dizer que você tem vários links que enviam o parâmetro `ID` diferente:

```html
<a href=produtos.php?id=1>Produto 1</a>
<a href=produtos.php?id=2>Produto 2</a>
<a href=produtos.php?id=3>Produto 3</a>
<a href=produtos.php?id=4>Produto 4</a>
```

E no **produtos.php** você resgata diretamente o valor e joga no `SELECT` (**o que não deve ser feito**):

```php
$id  = $_GET['id']; //aqui ele vai pegar qualquer coisa que você passar como valor do id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE ID=".$id; //aqui ele vai inserir o valor do id
```

**Notou o risco na segurança??** quem quiser, pode simplesmente por dedução saber que você está fazendo isto(do qual é uma coisa muito básica) e executar mais comandos no seu script como um `DELETE` por exemplo e acabar com o seu banco.

## Resposta: "Como resolver este problema?"

Bom, há vários métodos a se fazer, depende de de cada programador, porém eu gosto de sempre manipular a variável antes, verificar o tipo correto, e até as vezes limitar o tamanho dela, para garantir que não seja um script malicioso e sim minha informação, caso contrário, não execute o sql, por exemplo:

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (is_numeric($id)) //verifica se é um numero retorna true do contrario retorna false
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE ID=".$id;
```

Desta forma por exemplo, só executaria o sql se `$id` fosse um número, então impedindo qualquer tentativa de injetar um script.

Porém há outras maneiras outras formas de realizar verificações do tipo, o objetivo apenas é: **Limitar ao máximo os parâmetros que você utiliza para script's SQL, ou não utilizar parâmetros.**

Comment: [*Bobby Tables*](http://xkcd.com/327/) manda lembranças ;)